# How to transform a list of numbers into lists of consecutive numbers

Tags: elixir

I am trying to write a function that can transform a list of numbers into lists of consecutive numbers

For example, transforming a list of number such as this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 30, 32, 42, 43, 44, 45, 48, 49]
```

into lists of consecutive numbers such as this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21], [30], [32], [42, 43, 44, 45], [48, 49]]
```

Maybe I am overthinking this but I can't seem to come up with a good solution in elixir.

Appreciate any suggestions or pointers in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see two ways: using `Enum.chunk_while` that was introduced in 1.5.0 or using a by-hand recursion.

Here's a version using `Enum.chunk_while`:

```
chunk_fun = fn
  elem, [] -> {:cont, [elem]}
  elem, [prev | _] = acc when prev + 1 == elem -> {:cont, [elem | acc]}
  elem, acc -> {:cont, Enum.reverse(acc), [elem]} 
end
after_fun = fn
 [] -> {:cont, []} 
 acc -> {:cont, Enum.reverse(acc), []} 
end
Enum.chunk_while(list, [], chunk_fun, after_fun)
```

And here's a by-hand recursion version:

```
def chunk_cont([]), do: []
def chunk_cont([elem | list]), do: chunk_cont(list, elem, [])

defp chunk_cont([], elem, acc), do: [Enum.reverse(acc, [elem])]
defp chunk_cont([elem | list], prev, acc) when prev + 1 == elem do
  chunk_cont(list, elem, [prev | acc])
end
defp chunk_cont([elem | list], prev, acc) do
  [Enum.reverse(acc, [prev]) | chunk_cont(list, elem, [])]
end
```

Both versions do something similar. They iterate over the list and compare the current element to the previous one. If the current element is a "next" one, we push it onto the accumulator, if it's not, we reverse and emit the accumulator and continue our iteration with a new accumulator. Once finished we still can have some things left in the accumulator, if so we emit one last element.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I didn't know that you can also use pattern matching on anonymous functions. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 5):

While there are two correct answers already posted, I prefer using `Enum.reduce/3` over explicit recursion when possible and I believe this might be slightly more elegant than the `Enum.chunk_while/4` based solution already posted.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 30, 32, 42, 43, 44, 45, 48, 49]
|> Enum.reduce([], fn
  x, [] -> [[x]]
  x, [head = [h | _] | tail] when x == h + 1 -> [[x | head] | tail]
  x, [head | tail] -> [[x], head | tail]
end)
|> Enum.map(&Enum.reverse/1)
|> Enum.reverse
|> IO.inspect(charlists: :as_integers)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21], [30], [32], [42, 43, 44, 45], [48, 49]]
```

The core idea is this: I start with an empty list as the accumulator. Whenever an integer equals the latest integer in the accumulator + 1, I put it in the same list, otherwise I create a new list with that integer. At the end, the accumulator needs to be reversed and each list inside it also needs to be reversed.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thank you. Also, it seems like we are adding to the head of the list because the list is inherently a linked list underneath the hood?

Comment: Yes, that makes this more efficient and also allows us to use pattern matching to match on the most recently inserted value. Since everything is constructed in reverse, we need to reverse everything at the end. You'll see this pattern all the time in Elixir.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using only tail recursion, although it turned out rather complicated:

```
def chunk_cont([hd | rest]) do
  do_chunk_cont(rest, hd, [[hd]])
end

defp do_chunk_cont([hd | rest], last, [group | acc_rest]) when hd == last + 1 do
  do_chunk_cont(rest, hd, [[hd | group] | acc_rest])
end
defp do_chunk_cont([hd | rest], _last, [group | acc_rest]) do
  do_chunk_cont(rest, hd, [[hd] | [Enum.reverse(group) | acc_rest]])
end
defp do_chunk_cont([], _last, [group | acc_rest]) do
  [Enum.reverse(group) | acc_rest]
  |> Enum.reverse()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, based on @Dogbert solution, but with some modifications

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 30, 32, 42, 43, 44, 45, 48, 49]
|> Enum.reverse()
|> Enum.reduce([], fn
  x, [head = [h | _] | tail] when x == h - 1 -> [[x | head] | tail]
  x, acc -> [[x] | acc]
end)
|> IO.inspect(charlists: :as_integers)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21], [30], [32], [42, 43, 44, 45], [48, 49]]
```

Some advantages over @Dogbert solution:

1. There is only one reverse, without the many partial reverses.
2. Pattern matching is simpler to read.